# return error and stop funtion execution in a pythonc way

Tags: python, error-handling, return

I have a following funtion

```
def do_something():
  s = Process()
  result = s.p1(params)
  if result = fail then dont execute further 

  s.p2(params)
  s.p3(params)
  s.p4(params)
  s.p5(params)
```

```
class Process():

  def p1(does something):
    does something
    reuturns something
  .
  .
  .
  def p5(does something):
    does something
    reuturns something
```

The do_something function is run under multiple threads. What will be the threadsafe and pythonic way to handle the **return** statements in this case ? in case the return is FALSE I dont want to execute further in do_something()

Comment: Raise an error or return.

Comment: how do i use return here ? is string compare an efficient way to verify if the returned value meets conditions ?

Comment: If you want help with this, please show your actual use case. What does `p1` return?